# Python 3 - reading ID3 tags from audio stream

Tags: python-3.x, libraries, audio-streaming, id3

Can I read ID3 tags in Python? I found a lot of libraries in documentation but there isn't anyone, which supports reading ID3 tags from live audio stream. Really doesn't exit library for that? Or am I finding wrong? If you can, please help me. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [streamscrobbler](https://github.com/Dirble/streamscrobbler-python/blob/master/streamscrobbler.py) on python in order to read meta-Data from streaming MP3 / Radio-station.

`streamscrobbler` has dependencies on following modules.

```
httplib2 as http
httplib
re
urlparse
pprint
urllib2
```

Which can be installed as 
`pip install <module-name>`

Once they are installed though, its pretty straightforward to get meta-data [SHOUTcast/Icecast] info. It provides information such as:

Content-Type
Bit-rate
Description
Song-Name
URL
Server

### Sample Code

```
from streamscrobbler import streamscrobbler
streamscrobbler = streamscrobbler()

##streamurl can be a url directly of the stream or of a file.
streamurl = "http://pub1.di.fm/di_classictrance"

#All information available via streamscrobbler module
allData = streamscrobbler.getAllData(streamurl)
print ("allData =",allData)
```

### Output

```
   Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
parse headers: 
{   'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
    'ice-audio-info': 'bitrate=48000',
    'icy-br': '48000',
    'icy-description': 'DI.FM',
    'icy-genre': 'DI',
    'icy-metaint': '16000',
    'icy-name': 'Important Message',
    'icy-pub': '0',
    'icy-url': 'http://message-stream.audioaddict.com/3rdparty_di_english',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'server': 'Icecast 2.3.3-kh7'}
icy metaint: 16000
('allData =', {'status': 1, 'metadata': {'contenttype': 'audio/mpeg', 'bitrate': '48000', 'song': 'An important message from www.di.fm'}})
>>>
```